# We use access modifiers to limit the user access to protected/private variables, but how could the user even attempt to gain access to them?

Tags: oop, security, testing, access-modifiers, penetration-testing

If, for example, a developer is creating a desktop application or even a web app. How could a user go about exploiting access to variables/methods that should be protected/private but are declared public?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for this topic: [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for more information. It's not the normal user who will get access to your code, but 3rd parties will.

Comment: Well, assume that your program or system provides interfaces so that other systems can communicate with it or to use it as it is. The other endpoint now has the authority using this interface to do what this interface completely allows. If your design doesn't have access modifiers, then this endpoint can dive deep into your components and change the states and attributes of your components. Does that help?

Comment: I can see how that is a vulnerability. What if there is a public variable that is not set by any exposed endpoint, would endpoint requests still be the main exploit?

Comment: I can't understand your point well, but anyway you can't trust any endpoint as long as it's not part of your system. You must keep your state consistent and safe.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a normal user cannot access inner functions of the program. Only if you deliberately expose them then a normal user can gain access to them. The use of private / protected and public is mainly used for encapsulation purposes. This limits the amount of access points to the inner state of classes and libraries.

A bit higher up is module access, in case a module system is implemented. This lists the (public) methods that can be accessed from other modules. Beyond that you're getting into remote access through e.g. remote procedure calls or web-API's. Those need to be exposed as well.

Finally there is the user interface. The user interface generally doesn't have any access to public functions of a program. Only the general input / output is provided. Of course you must still make sure that you don't expose any of the inner state. Buffer overruns, RAM attacks and such can make a user completely skip all the protection offered by above measures.

So public / private can be a good way to limit access to the inner state of a program. But these access modifiers are generally not the first line of defense.